# Help Identify this Pink Flowering Landscape Plant

Tags: identification, flowers

This is a landscape plant at my mothers work she wants to identify. We live in upper South Carolina and it's currently in full bloom as of 3/27/2016. I've included pictures of a branch she snapped off. I've tried to included an overall picture as well as a close up of the leaves and the flowers. The flowers seem to be pretty distinct, being magenta, thin, and wavy, multipetal flowers.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Looks like Chinese fringe flower / Loropetalum chinensis

http://www.absolutewonder.com/loropetalum.html